# Почему сложение числа с массивом выдает строку?

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки

Как видно из примера ниже, массив и число складываются как строки.

```js
console.log([5] + 25); //525
```

Почему так происходит? При выполнении сложения для массива запускается метод `toString`? Разве метод `toString` не должен запускаться только при попытке преобразования объекта к строке (`String`, `alert`...)? А в этом случае я не пытаюсь преобразовать массив к строке...

Comment: А что вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: Поскольку оператор сложения используется и для конкатенации строк, интерпретатор не может быть уверен, что вы не хотите его так использовать. Подробнее см. https://learn.javascript.ru/object-toprimitive

Comment: а у массивов нет [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Согласно Флэнагану (JavaScript. Полное руководство, 7-е издание - 2021):

> Операция + в JavaScript выполняет сложение чисел и конкатенацию строк.
> Если любой из ее операндов оказывается объектом, то интерпретатор
> JavaScript преобразует его в элементарное значение с применением
> алгоритма no-preference. После получения двух элементарных значений
> проверяются их типы. Если один из аргументов является строкой, тогда
> другой преобразовывается в строку и выполняется конкатенация строк.

То есть, массив преобразуется в строку, почему:

> Алгоритм no-preference зависит от класса преобразуемого объекта. Если
> объект относится к классу Date, тогда интерпретатор JavaScript
> применяет алгоритм prefer-string. Для любого другого объекта
> интерпретатор JavaScript использует агоритм prefer-number.
>
> Алгоритм prefer-number первым испытывает valueOf(), а вторым -
> toString().

(Если valueOf() не существует или возвращает объект). Другими словами, массив должен бы преобразоваться в число, НО:

> Класс Array наследует стандартный метод valueOf(), который не
> возвращает элементарное значение. Таким образом, когда мы пытаемся
> преобразовать массив в число, то в итоге получаем вызов метода
> toString() массива.
>
> Массив с единственным элементом преобразуется в ту же строку, что и
> этот один элемент. Если массив содержит единственное число, то оно
> преобразуется в строку.

Таким образом, массив, в силу того, что его метод valueOf() возвращает сам массив как объект, в итоге возвращает результат вызова toString().

**Для эксперимента можно переписать метод valueOf():**

```js
Array.prototype.valueOf = function(){
    return Number(this[0]);
}
console.log([5] + 25);
```

**То, что возвращает родной valueOf() для сравнения:**

```js
console.log([5].valueOf());
```